# Why doesn't Logger.log work any more with HTML Service

Tags: google-apps-script

Recently I notice that Logger.log is not working if a function is called from HTML Service.

In my HTML :

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
  function(text) {
    alert(text);
  }
).setColors(checked);
```

In Code.gs:

```
function setColors(checked) {
  try {
    Logger.log(checked);
    return "hello";
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

The "hello" is returned but the log is empty, or actually its a log from a previous test function unrelated.  And "checked" is displayed in an alert box after google.script.run and its correct.

Comment: Known issue. If you search, you'd find a duplicate. Use `console` with stackdriver.

Comment: I don't think this is a recent issue.  I have been using Logger.log to check data passed back and forth from/to server for year now.  It is only recenly that it stopped working.  By the way I use the old editor.

Comment: When they first came out with the "New Editor" there was a delay in when the log file would be available to look at.  I think they have now done that for the old editor.  When I run a simple test the log is not available to view for a while.  But that doesn't resolve the problem with HTML server calls.  That log never appears.  It seems they are forcing us to use the ne editor and stackdriver log.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using new editor, in "Executions" menu you need to look for last executed function, which suppose to log. In your case `setColors()`. If nothing have been logged, give some time and try refreshing. It hints, that it takes some time for logs to appear.

Comment: So an old dog can learn new tricks.  I see now with the new editor there is a console log displayed below the code.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was my reluctance to use the new editor because of the issue with delay in Logger.log.  But now I can see a lot of advantages to using the new editor, although it takes some exploration and effort to find how to do things like find and replace.

But there are a lot of advantages to the new editor and console.log and exection log for debugging. console.log is displayed in the editor along with the code for stand alone running and debugging of scripts.  And the console.log and execution log work for HTML service request.  So for now I'm a happy camper :)